# counting the number of elements in a given string

Tags: xml, xslt

i want to count no. of ';' in the below string and also split the values separated by ';' individually

input string:- TELEPHON;EMERGENC;FAX62TC;BS21;BS22;BS23;BS24;BS25;BS26

Comment: Which language do you use?

Comment: Show an effort.

Comment: It has 8 ';' characters.

Comment: splitting the value seems simple but could not find a clearer way to count ';'

Comment: Counting and splitting are two different things. Please show the exact output you expect to get, and also state if using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Answer (score 2):

One way to count the number of occurrences of a certain character in a string is to remove all other characters and then use string-length. With XPath 2.0 you can simply use `string-length(replace($str, '[^;]+', ''))`, but even with XPath 1.0 if you use `translate` twice, where `translate($str, ';', '')` gives you all characters which are not semicolons and then `translate($str, translate($str, ';', ''), '')` gives you the string with only semicolons you can the use `string-length(translate($str, translate($str, ';', ''), '')` to count the characters.

Comment: Why go for a heavy-weight tool like XPath, when one or two simple bash build-in is sufficient?

Comment: @D.Kovács, the poster tagged the question as xslt so XPath as the expression language used in XSLT seems an appropriate tool.

Comment: @MartinHonnen indeed, my bad, it's Friday evening.

Comment: Sir, Very nice regular expression for count the particular text. Plus one.

Answer (score 0):

`echo "my;test;string;it;is" | sed 's/[^;]//g' | wc -c` should do the trick for counting.

`echo "my;test;string;it;is" | tr ';' '\n'` should do the trick for splitting (replace `\n` with your choice of split character)

Comment: This question is tagged `xslt`. What language is your answer?

Comment: @michael.hor257k indeed, my bad, it's Friday evening. I'd still leave it as reference. If the community wants, I'll delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Use of `string-length` (mentioned in previous answer) would be enough if you were interested **only** in counting occurrences of a character in a string.

But as you want also to **split** this string, you need to use `tokenize` function.
It does the 2nd part of your task - splits the string using a given token, in this case `';'`.

The number of occurrences of ';' (the 1st part of your task) you can get from
the number of elements in the result array (`count` function) minus one.

For your input converted to a proper XML sample:

```
<root>
  <entry>TELEPHON;EMERGENC;FAX62TC;BS21;BS22;BS23;BS24;BS25;BS26</entry>
</root>
```

run the following XSLT to demonstrate the result.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/root/entry">
    <xsl:text>Entry: </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>

    <!-- Split the string -->
    <xsl:variable name="tbl" select="tokenize(., ';')"/>
    <!-- # of semicolons -->
    <xsl:variable name="cnt" select="count($tbl) - 1"/>
    <xsl:text># of ';': </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$cnt"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>

    <!-- Show each substring -->
    <xsl:for-each select="$tbl">
      <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
      <xsl:text>. </xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```